# Как запустить файл через приложение?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Каким способом можно перехватить запуск файла через приложение?

Например, к файлу `C:\app.exe` обращается файл `test.txt`, этот файл должен открыться при условии, что в приложении есть разрешение на запуск такого имени файла. Если разрешения нет, то запретить запуск.

Файл `app.exe` это приложение в которое должно разрешать или запрещать запуск файлов по имени. Если файл `test.txt` (или любой другой) прописан каким либо образом внутри приложения `app.exe`, то ему разрешено запускаться. Пользователь перемещает файл на приложение, и приложение решает, можно разрешать файлу открыться или нет (по имени файла).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каким образом хранится разрешение? Кто дает?

Comment: Разрешение в самом приложении `C:\app.exe` если самое простое, для более сложной задачи, было бы неплохо иметь список разрешений в реестре. Чтобы приложение считывало имена разрешенных файлов.

Comment: "к файлу C:\app.exe обращается файл test.txt" - это что значит?

Comment: Допустим, перетягиваем курсором мыши файл `test.txt` на приложение `app.exe` и текстовик открывается, если ему разрешено по имени. Суть в том, чтобы приложение могло разрешать или запрещать запуск файлов, через себя.

Comment: Это нужно делать из `app.exe` или `app` — стороннее приложение, которому Вы хотите запретить запуск какого-то файла? В общем напишите подробно по шагам в тексте вопроса что должно происходить для разрешенного и запрещенного файла.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: У метода входа в приложение `Main` есть список входных параметров: `string[] args`. При старте приложения смотрите этот список, сравниваете со списком разрешённых/запрещённых файлов, действуете как нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но Ваш уровень знаний и мой, как бы отличается в 7000 раз.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что вместо нормальной настройки прав доступа средствами ОС, вы пытаетесь изобрести свой велосипед. Ответьте на простой вопрос: что мешает пользователю переименовать интересующий его файл в тот, который у него уже открывался и обойти вашу защиту? А теперь опишите настоящую задачу, которую пытаетесь решить таким странным образом.

Comment: Просто нужен белый список файлов, чтобы пользователь мог только свои файлы разрешать, а остальные не запускались.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точкой входа в любое приложение является метод `Main` по умолчанию. У него есть (может быть) список входных параметров `args`. Если программа будет запущена, когда на неё перетащен какой-либо файл, то имя этого файла будет в этом списке.

Соответственно, достаточно проверить это имя со списком разрешённых файлов.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Файлы, разрешённые к обработке.
    // "Белый" список.
    var whitelist = new HashSet<string>
    {
        @"C:\test.txt",
        @"C:\test2.txt"
    };

    if (args.Any() && whitelist.Contains(args[0]))
    {
        // Обработка разрешена
    }
    else
    {
        // Обработка запрещена
        return; // завершаем программу
    }

    // другой код
}
```

Comment: Не выходит, файл не запускается, хоть и есть в списке. Нужно, чтобы блокнот открылся для `test.txt`, т.е. как обычный запуск текстового документа.

Comment: @Vitokhv - Ну так покажите код, как открываете Блокнот.

Comment: Вы когда переносите файл, он у Вас открывается? Что если это будет, например изображение, ему тоже придется показывать код как открыться?

Comment: Спасибо, в первый раз не верно проверил. Если будет возможность, подскажите как сделать запуск только расширения *.txt с любым именем?